# ip camera foscam on wifi, only works on wifi on local network

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, camera

I am so confused, I have the foscam F18908W and the neufbox router NB4.

```
when plugged directly to the router
- i can connect to it using another computer on the network
- i can connect to it externally 

when using the wifi
- i can connect to it using another computer on the network
- i can not connect it to externally!
```

what does that mean??? The wifi camera connection works since I can access it from another local computer but what would make it not work externally if it works with the wire... this makes no sense

Comment: have you assigned it a static IP address and setup port forwarding (and opened up the firewall if one is present) on your router?

Comment: yes, it actually works from an external connection only when the camera is connected with the wire! If I try to connect from the outside when the camera is on wifi it does not work! But it works fro, within the local network that's why I'm so confused